# Error connecting Bluetooth to extended broadcast device

Tags: c++

1.When using the esp32-s3-devkitc-1 development board for development, the function connect() always fails to connect when connecting to an extended broadcast device. The device can be scanned using the extended scan method and the MAC address is accurate.

The C++ code is as follows:

```
bool ConnectToServer(esp_bd_addr_t addr)
{
    BLEClient *pClient = BLEDevice::createClient();      // 创建客户端
    pClient->setClientCallbacks(new MyClientCallback()); // 添加客户端与服务器连接与断开回调功能
    if (pClient->isConnected())
        pClient->disconnect();
    pClient->setMTU(240);

    // std::string strAdd = "30:c0:7e:68:49:1d";
    // std::string strAdd = "30:C0:7E:68:49:1D";

    if (!pClient->connect(BLEAddress(addr))) // 
    {
        log("connect fail!!!\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    log("connect success!!!\r\n");

    pRemoteService = pClient->getService(SERVER_START_UPGRADE_UUID); // 尝试获取设备中的服务
    if (pRemoteService == nullptr)
    {
        log("get server fail !!!\r\n");
        pClient->disconnect();
        return false;
    }
    log("get server success !!! \r\n");

    pRemoteCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(CHARA_START_UPGRADE_UUID); // 
    if (pRemoteCharacteristic == nullptr)
    {
        log("get characteristic fail !!!\r\n");
        pClient->disconnect();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The function connect() was able to connect successfully

Comment: *"the function connect() always fails to connect"* and *"The function connect() was able to connect successfully"* seem contradictory... Please re-read your text and edit as needed to clarify.

Comment: Then, don't these methods or classes have any way to report error code or or error message?

Comment: I use the esp_ble_gattc_aux_open function instead  of  that esp_ble_gattc_open in connect().then it works successfully.

Comment: If you solved this, and can be bothered to do so, then feel free to write your own answer! Even if it just shows that single code change, it may help someone else in the future. And if you know _why_ this fix works, please tell.